# Multiple select in materialize-css with angular2 not rendering dynamic values

Tags: typescript, angular, materialize, multiple-select

I am using **angular2-materialize** with **materialize-css** to work with **angular2**. Everything **works fine even the normal select component** .
**the problem is with multiple select** **it doesn't render the dynamic values** , I don't understand if its the issue with the initializing object or something else as it works for a normal select but if i add static options and after rendering if I click that option then **change event is called and then if I click it again all those dynamic values gets added to the combo**.

Below is my code but if there is not any proper solution i can work with any **workaround** or any other framework than materialize-css which is tested and works proper with angular2.

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <!--if i remoe multiple it works-->
            <select 
                    materialize="material_select"  
                    multiple 
                    (ngModelChange)="change($event)" 
                    [ngModel]="prodmodel.CategoryId"
                    ngControl="CategoryId" #catid="ngForm">
                <!--This options are not rendering-->
                <option *ngFor="#p of categories"
                        [value]="p.id">
                    {{p.CategoryTitle}}
                </option>
                <!--This option will render and if i click it above options will render too but not in oproper way-->
                <option value="0">chhose</option>
            </select>
            <label>select Category </label>
        </div>
```

**My function to get categories**:

```
    getCategories() {
    this._Categories.getCategories()
        .subscribe(
        Categories=> this.Categories= Categories,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Comment: Where do the `categories` values come from?

Comment: Can you try to reproduce with this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/sQGRzC?p=preview ?

Comment: hi.. haven't used plunkr yet.. how can i add materialize-css and angular2-materialize in that plunkr?

Comment: I don't know materialize-css and angular2-materialize :-/

Comment: thanks a lot , but its and issue with angular2-materialize itself and the guy is working on it on github.. willl put the answer when its done current workaround is $('#select').material_select()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved now with the latest version of angular2-materialize. See bug and fix details here: https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/21

This is how you can trigger updates to select option elements (using **materializeSelectOptions**):

```js
<select materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="selectOptions">
  <option *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" [value]="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```